# WPF - Set SelectedItem property using the ItemsSource property

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, telerik

I am trying to override the [RadDataFilter ControlTemplates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11895703/trying-to-build-a-query-builder-control-in-wpf) and I used the Custom UserControl. I have 2 dependency properties in my class:

```
  public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItem", typeof(object), typeof(CustomControl), new UIPropertyMetadata());

  public object SelectedItem
  {
     get { return (object)GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
     set { SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value); }
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource"
        , typeof(IEnumerable)
        , typeof(CustomControl));
        //, new PropertyMetadata(RadDataFilter.OnItemsSourcePropertyChanged));

  public IEnumerable ItemsSource
  {
     get
     {
        return this.GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty) as IEnumerable;
     }
     set
     {
        this.SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value);
     }
  }
```

and in my XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="RADDataFilterExample.CustomControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" >
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Content="Shankar" Click="Button_Click" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

The place where I am using this control is here:

```
<local:CustomControl x:Name="PART_SimpleFilterMemberComboBox" Content="Finally!!"
                                        Margin="0,0,3,0" MinWidth="100" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                        ItemsSource="{Binding SimpleFilter.AvailableMembers}"
                                        SelectedItem="{Binding SimpleFilter.SelectedMember, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

where the SimpleFilter.AvailableMembers and SimpleFilter.SelectedMember are part of Telerik Source Code.

Now my question is, how do I set the SelectedItem property from my CustomControl?

Please let me know.

Comment: What datatype is AvailableMembers? And I think you need to set the SelectedValuePath and DisplayMemberPath values too, if your custom control is custom combobox

Comment: ICollection<ItemPropertyDefinitionViewModel> is the type of AvailableMembers. ItemPropertyDefinitionViewModel is again a Telerik class.. What should I set the SelectedValuePath to? The one on my custom control or the one in Telerik code?

Also, my custom control is not a combobox but different one..

Comment: Oh, where do you set your DataContext for your control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the binding to work, somehow the binding was not happening for SimpleFilter.SelectedMember. Instead I had binding set for the SimpleFilter object and then setting its properties from the Custom Control.